# What are my options for automating Firefox?

Tags: firefox, automation

My goal is to hit different shortcuts on my keyboard which then open new Firefox windows and open a list of URLs in tabs inside those windows.

What are all the options I have for doing this, specifically on MacOS?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Beyond the simple (but effective) answer already provided, you could also look at using [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) (assuming you wanted to actually automate page interactions via Python afterwards). MacOS also has software that can be used for [keyboard automation](https://www.google.com/search?q=macos+keyboard+automation), including Automator/AppleScript, Keyboard Maestro, and yKey (the latter two being paid software).

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut like that:

```
<path_to_firefox>\firefox.exe "url1" "url2" "url3" ...
```